# Concavity of $(x+y)^c$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I want to show that the function $(x+y)^{c}$, with $x,y\geq0$ and $c\in(0,1)$. From the definition of concavity, it amounts to show

\begin{align}
(\lambda x_{0} + \lambda y_{0} +  (1-\lambda) x_{1} + (1-\lambda) y_{1})^{c} \geq \lambda(x_{0}+y_{0})^{c} + (1-\lambda)(x_{1}+y_{1})^{c} 
\end{align}

and the Hessian is given by

$$
H = c(c-1)(x+y)^{c-2}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1  \\
  1 & 1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

However, I seem to be missing something.

Comment: It is fine, since $H \le 0$ you see that the function $(x,y) \mapsto  (x+y)^c$ is concave.

Comment: so it is indeed concave?

Comment: @copper.hat: Consider the matrix $H=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -2\\-2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ with eigenvalues $-3$ (eigenvector $(1,1)$) and $1$ (eigenvector $(1,-1)$), which is the Hessian of the corresponding quadratic form $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{\mathrm{t}}Hx$. For $g(t)=f(t(1,-1))$ we have $g(t)=t^2$, which is convex, not concave. The required condition is that $H$ is negative semidefinite (not that the entries are non-positive).

Comment: @Matija $H \le 0$ means $H$ is negative semi definite, not that the entries are all negative.

Comment: This makes sense exactly if $H$ is the quadratic form, in which case the inequality $H\le 0$ follows the convention for functions $f\le 0$. When we consider $H$ as a point in $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ (that is a function $H:[2]\times[2]\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $(i,j)\mapsto H_{i,j}$), then the inequality $H\le 0$ is the canonical pointwise inequality. In a nutshell: It seems that this notation is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=(x+y)^c$, further let $v_0=(x_0,y_0)$, $v_1=(x_1,y_1)$ be such that $x_0+y_0$, $x_1+y_1\ge 0$, $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and $v_\lambda=(x_\lambda,y_\lambda)=\lambda v_1+(1-\lambda)v_0$. If one sum is $0$, say $x_0+y_0=0$, we have $f(v_\lambda)=\lambda^cf(v_1)\ge\lambda f(v_1)+(1-\lambda)f(v_0)$ using $f(v_0)=0$ and $c\in(0,1)$. Otherwise let $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $t\mapsto f(v_t)$. For $t\in[0,1]$ we have $x_t+y_t=t(x_1+y_1)+(1-t)(x_0+y_0)>0$, so $g'(t)=c(x_t+y_t)^{c-1}\Delta$, where $\Delta=x_1+y_1 -x_0-y_0$, and $g''(t)=c(c-1)(x_t+y_t)^{c-2}\Delta^2$. Using $c\in(0,1)$ we have $g''(t)<0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ (take one sided derivatives or slightly extend $g$ in both directions). Hence, for any $0\le t\le s\le 1$ we have $g'(s)-g'(t)=\int_t^sg''(u)\mathrm du\le0$ with equality if and only if $t=s$.
This shows that the derivative is strictly decreasing. Using the mean value theorem with $g(1)-g(0)=\int_0^1g'(t)\mathrm dt$ we obtain $t^*\in[0,1]$ with $g'(t^*)=g(1)-g(0)$. In particular, for $h:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $t\mapsto g'(t^*)t+g(0)$ we have $h(1)=g(1)$. With $g'(0)=\int_0^1g'(0)\mathrm dt>\int_0^1g'(t)\mathrm dt=g'(t^*)$, and analogously $g'(1)<g'(t^*)$, we have $t^*\in(0,1)$, so $g(t)=g(0)+\int_0^{t}g'(u)\mathrm du>g(0)+g'(t^*)t=h(t)$ for $t\in(0,t^*]$.
Assume there exists $t\in(t^*,1)$ with $g(t)\le h(t)$, then $g(1)=g(t)+\int_t^1g'(u)\mathrm du<h(t)+g'(t^*)(1-t)=h(1)=g(1)$ is a contradiction, so $g(t)>h(t)$ for all $t\in (0,1)$, in particular $f(v_\lambda)=g(\lambda)>h(\lambda)=f(v_0)+g'(t^*)\lambda=\lambda f(v_1)+(1-\lambda) f(v_0)$, since $g'(t^*)=g(1)-g(0)=f(v_1)-f(v_0)$. This shows that $f$ is convex on the maximal domain given by $x+y\ge 0$, and strictly convex on the interior.

Although we avoided the Hessian alltogether, we have $g''<0$ because $H$ is negative definite. However, I prefer to consider $g$ (instead of $f$) from the very beginning, since this reduces the multidimensional case to the one-dimensional case, without affecting the arguments.
Also, should this not be clear, any function for which the Hessian exists everywhere and is negative semidefinite, is concave (cf. the remark [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) that clarifies the relation of concave and convex functions, and the remark [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) that relates convexity to the Hessian).